# Get Current User's Department Name and Manager From Active Directory

Tags: 2010, active-directory, custom-form

How the "department name" and "manager" attribute value could be retrieved from active directory programmatically? For ex. i will have custom newform.aspx to create some new item, in the code-behind of the custom newform.aspx i have to send email to the manager of the current user, and log the department name. So sharepoint designer activities is not suitable for my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below code access current user's department and manager from AD:

```
    SPSite _site = SPContext.Current.Site;
   ServerContext serverContext = ServerContext.GetContext(_site);
   UserProfileManager myUserProfile = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
   UserProfile currentUserProfile = myUserProfile .GetUserProfile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

   string departmentName = (string)currentUserProfile["department"].Value;
   string managerName = (string)currentUserProfile["manager"].Value;
   _site.RootWeb.Dispose();
   _site.Dispose();
```

The other way to do this is to use DirectoryEntry and DirectorSearcher class:

[1. Get user details from Active Directory](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-get-userdetails-from-active.html)

[2. How to get user data from Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6778/How-to-get-User-Data-from-the-Active-Directory)

[3. All operation on AD using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/all-operations-on-active-directory-ad-using-C-Sharp/)

---

Converting string to SPUser

---

```
string managerName = (string)currentUserProfile["manager"].Value;

SPFieldUserValue _spUserValue = new SPFieldUserValue(myWeb, managerName);

SPUser myUser = _spUserValue.User;
```

Note: myWeb is the object of SPWeb class

Example:

```
SPSite _site = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWeb myWeb = _site.OpenWeb();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @zakir hc, one more thing: what is the return value of currentUserUserProfile["manager"].Value ? Can i cast it to SPUser object? So that i can get the email of manager..

Comment: Hi ozdogan, the return value will be string and yes you can cast it to SPUser. Please check my above edited answer.

Comment: How to do this in Client Object Model (javascript)?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note that **ServerContext** Class has been deprecated and replaced with **SPServiceContext** below is the updated Code

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url) )
                                {
                                        SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                                        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

                                        UserProfile currentUserProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(item.ClaimID);
                                        item.Department = Convert.ToString(currentUserProfile[PropertyConstants.Department].Value);
                                        item.Email =Convert.ToString(currentUserProfile[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].Value) ;
                                        //string managerName = (string)currentUserProfile["manager"].Value;

                                }
```