# Getting AD Information

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service

I need to certain information. I read that it is not possible to get AD information unless you have some sort of solution that accesses it.

So the other option is the SharePoint user profiles.

How can I access it and get the information I want to display it... ie work phone, email, name... etc.

I need to create a directory.

Comment: Hi mkhan, do you need to access user AD information from your SharePoint code or you want something else?

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you use? Foundation? Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch information form AD from your SharePoint Code/Solution, here is a reference you may be interested in:
[Get user data from AD](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62929/get-current-users-department-name-and-manager-from-active-directory)

In the above given reference you can add your required data to be fetched, example:

```
string telephoneNumber = (string)currentUserProfile["telephoneNumber"].Value;
string mail = (string)currentUserProfile["mail"].Value;
string firstName = (string)currentUserProfile["givenName"].Value;
etc......
```

Check this you will get all AD property names: [AD properties names](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-get-userdetails-from-active.html)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPServices to achieve this but if you are looking to create a directory I would be tempted to customise a people search web part.